# Generate Dynamic PDF

Tags: vue.js, pdf, vuejs3

Is there is any way to download vue js code as PDF or make a file of that to upload on server
But code is dynamic and there are some condition as well to render code.
and I have to also add some images while generating PDF.

I have tried :

[vue-html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf)

[html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)

[jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=jspdf)

[pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib)

and when ever required also combine this packages but noting work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.